# using selenium to click a link hidden by contentreplace with selenium xpath

Tags: javascript, python, xpath, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm writing a script in python using the selenium chrome webdriver, and I want to click on a link. The link itself is:

a href="javascript:contentReplace('/cgi-bin/ssol/9PGaiwzaxu43ZaLXZ8mAix/?p%.5Fr%.5Fid=a5UAMSbnZrZMIowCvr5gzh&p%.5Ft%.5Fid=1&tran%.5B1%.5D%.5Fentry=student&tran%.5B1%.5D%.5Ftran%.5Fname=sreg')">Registration/a>

(I took off the opening < of the link elements so as to be able to display the code, not the text, in the browser)

I couldn't locate it using find_element_by_link_text--it kept throwing an error--so I tried using the xpath. I used firebug to get the xpath, and it is: "/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/ul/li/ul/li[10]/a"

But when I do
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/ta\
ble/tbody/tr[2]/td/ul/li/ul/li[10]/a")

I get an error of "urlopen error [Errno 61] Connection refused"

Not sure what's wrong, since the xpath works in firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Registration").click()
```

Why can't you record the script in **Selenium IDE** ? It will directly give the **xpath** to the link when you click on it.

If you want code, then post the **link to webpage** where you are clicking on that `link`. So that it will be easy to give answer.

Comment: I just recorded the script in Selenium IDE, and it works great--problem is, even with the xpaths it gives me, my python script still gets the error mentioned above. 
For example, the ide gives me:   //table[@id='MainMenu']/tbody/tr[2]/td/ul/li/ul/li[10]/a
 as the xpath, so I have written 
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='MainMenu']/tbody/tr[2]/td\
/ul/li/ul/li[10]/a")but it says connection refused.

I would post the link to the webpage, but it's a secure page that requires login information to get to.